# Reverse-proxy apache

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse

I have an apache (port 80) and an extra webserver which runs on port 8000 (openslides). If I use foobar.com:8000 it works. But it is not user-optimized and in some hotels have damn firewalls..
I want a redirection from foobar.com to foobar.com:8000.
My config is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin ...@..
ServerName foobar.com
ServerAlias www.foobar.com
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/openslides.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/openslides-access.log combined
<Location foobar.com>
      ProxyPass  http://foobar.com:8000
      ProxyPassReverse http://foobar.com:8000
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

foobar.com:8000 runs, but for foobar.com I get an empty site. Do anyone see the mistake in the config?

Thanks!

bengoshi

Comment: Any message in the error log? - If not, try `LogLevel debug`. Apache will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: is extra webserver running in the same host as apache?

Comment: You do not need the Location tags at all.  Then for proxy errors, put your log level to debug and check the error log.  It you try `telnet foobar.com 8000` on the system that runs Apache, does it connect?

Comment: Yes and extra webserver is running, too and is necessary. But I took an own domain for this case / redirection. So apache listen to port 80 and the reverse proxy should redirect foobar.com to port 8000; but anothersite.com to port 80/apache.

I restart apache2 with LogLevel debug, but the results modest...
[Fri Jan 26 10:27:20.586237 2018] [proxy:debug] [pid 17439] proxy_util.c(1864): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 17439 for (foobar.com)

Comment: I tried to use it without a Location-tag. The apache configtest failed:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/foobar.conf:
ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch needs a path when not defined in a location
Action 'configtest' failed.

telnet foobar.com 8000 was successful. It is able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

You got the `Location` tag wrong. You need to put a path in there:

```
<Location />
      ProxyPass  http://foobar.com:8000
      ProxyPassReverse http://foobar.com:8000
</Location>
```

For more info about the `Location` tag see: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location

Comment: Thanks a lot but it doesn't help. The result is the same. I have read the apache-doc but I was not able to see my fault..